# Unexpected token 'export' in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to use google location autocomplete but getting this error :

> SyntaxError Unexpected token 'export'

this is the link to the working code :

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-bardeen-5eock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main.js you're putting the wrong path, instead of `import VueGoogleAutocomplete from "vue-google-autocomplete";`,you should do `import VueGoogleAutocomplete from "./components/VueGoogleAutocomplete.vue";`